# Path for global figures

Tags: floats, paths, linux

I know that I can save some styles files to be used for all users simply loading it on preamble.

I'd like to know where save some figures to have the same effect, that is, any user could insert the figures as they can do with the style files.

ps: I'm using texlive on Linux.

Comment: In `localtexmf` !..

Comment: @HarishKumar, it would be `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` or some subfolder there?

Comment: You can create a sub-folder inside `texmf-local` and put the figures there to avoid cluttering.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I did it and run `texhash` but I got error`Package pdftex.def Error: File `logo.jpg' not found \includegraphics{logo.jpg}`.

Comment: I am not on texlive now. Sorry can't test it :(

Answer (score 5):

Following suggestion above and below I'd discovered where to put the figures:

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/images
```

After that, I run `texhash` as root and it works.

Now I can insert those figures simply using `\includegraphics`.

Comment: you might want to take a look at the tds (tex directory structure) manual -- `texdoc tds`.  in section 4 (p.12) there is a suggested location for "common" graphics: "`.../tex/generic/images/` image input files (e.g. encapsulated postscript)".  (this would logically be a branch of the `texmf-local` tree.)  `images` seems a more meaningful name than just `local`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, should I create the folder `image`? I can not find one in my TeXlive distribution.

Comment: the `local` tree is yours to manage.  i've just examined the local tree on the system i'm using (a shared production system based on tex live 2012) and there *is* a branch `...tex/latex/local` as you mention, and it is empty; it must have been created when the system was built.  i've also reread the tds manual, which states that "`local` may occur at any level" (p.12), and also says (in several places) that the name `local` is reserved for local additions.  i'm still inclined to think that `images` is better because it identifies exactly what's there.